# Get Custom Document Information Panel metadata within Word

Tags: ms-office, infopath, infopath2010, office-2010

I have created a custom DIP using InfoPath, the XML was generated manually as their is no SharePoint document library available.  The DIP was created first by creating the basic XML stucture as a blank InfoPath template and then reimporting the generated XML to create a DIP.

The DIP appears in the word document correctly, however I cannot find a way to use the custom data from the DIP within the word document.  The custom fields do not appear in the fields under quick links, neither can I reference the fields manually.

Any help would be much appreaciated.

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: design a XML to store all your information.
Step 2: add this XML as a customXMLPart (e.g. using macros: activeDocument.CustomXMLParts.Add(xmlString))
Step 3: insert some content controls in your word document 
Step 4: map the content control to your customXML part using XPath expressions. (e.g. activedocument.contentcontrols(1).XMLMapping.SetMapping "myxpath-expression"
step 5: create the DIP in InfoPath using the XML you designed earlier
step 6: in Word indicate you want the new .xsn-file as a DIP

Then the DIP will be able to manage the CustomXML in your document. As the XML is directly mapped to the content controls, editing information through the DIP will immediately change information in your content controls.

Hope this helps. Maybe not for the original poster, but for people who will find this later.